# Laravel 5 database relationship - get data on another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 table. 
I need to jump movie_name from reservations.
I have allready getting data from showtime but I can not go forward there.

```
reservations->id - I am getting showtime_id clumn (its ok.) 
$reservation->showtime['movie_id'] - I am getting movie_id (its ok.)
But I need movie name.
```

Database

```
- reservations
id
showtime_id
....

- showtimes
id
movie_id
..

- movies
id
movie_name
..
```

My View

```
@foreach ($reservations as $reservation)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$reservation->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$reservation->fullname}}</td>
    <td>{{$reservation->showtime['movie_time']}}</td>
    <td>Movie Name</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I have listing reservations like this. My Controller

```
public function Reservations()
{
    $reservations = \App\Reservation::paginate(20);
    return view('admin.reservations', ['reservations' => $reservations]);
}
```

My Modal

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    public function showtime(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Showtime');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a relationship in Showtime model for retrieving the movie which is related to it.

```
// Showtime.php
public function movie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
}
```

And now you can access it.

```
$reservation->showtime->movie->movie_name;
```